# Technicolor TG582n admin login

Tags: linux, authentication, router, dump, bin

So I have been looking for hours to find the login to this router using upper and lower case and have got absolutely no where at all and have tried factory reset as well.

The reason I have come here for a possible solution is that I have a dump of the flash chip from the board. I bought it cheap off ebay as we have the same router at work and I am deploying some IP cams there in the near future, for the router at work we have the same problem but a call to our ISP may sort this. The seller said it was from Woav but they don't want to know as the previous owner has no account with them now neither do I.

I tried programming an OpenWrt firmware to the chip but it never booted so went back to the original image. Here is the original image for the chip (cFeon EN25Q64). From some reading it seems the systum is linux based.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmfbf4bu1px3tsd/Technicolor%20TG582n.rar?dl=0

If someone can help me out here it will be greatly appreciated.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I found this article [flashing-generic-firmware-on-a-technicolor-tg582n](http://www.jonathandavis.me.uk/2013/12/flashing-generic-firmware-on-a-technicolor-tg582n/) which says the username is ‘Administrator’ and the password is the serial number printed on the bottom. I can confirm this for my router.

Comment: I tried this in various combinations of upper and lower case in both username and password fields

Comment: Alas I think some ISP change them from the default.